# DrawPixels with PACK Pixel Buffer Object

Tags: opengl

guys,
In the GLUT display() function, I read the pixel into a PACK buffer object.

```
// Read the frame buffer into the binded read stream.
glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, bufferObject[RetrievingPixelBuffer]);
glReadPixels(0,0,width, height, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));

GLfloat* pixels = (GLfloat*) glMapBuffer( GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, GL_READ_WRITE);
for( int i = 0; i <width*height; i++)
{
    *pixels = 1.0;
    pixels+=4;
}
glUnmapBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER);

glDrawPixels(width, height, GL_RGBA,
             GL_FLOAT, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));
```

And I read and update the pixel data content, and draw it into frame buffer again.

But the glDrawPixels return GL_invalid_operation. Is there something wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: This is probably the most arcane way to clear a framebuffer, I've seen so far. glClearColor(1., 1., 1., 1.); glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); is far easier ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using a PBO `glDrawPixels` operates on a `GL_UNPACK_BUFFER`. You have only a `GL_PACK_BUFFER` bound. You need to unbind the buffer object from the pack binding, then bind it to the unpack binding and call `glDrawPixels` then.

**EDIT code for clarification**

```
// Read the frame buffer into the binded read stream.
glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, bufferObject[RetrievingPixelBuffer]);
glReadPixels(0,0,width, height, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));

GLfloat* pixels = (GLfloat*) glMapBuffer( GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, GL_READ_WRITE);
for( int i = 0; i <width*height; i++)
{
    *pixels = 1.0;
    pixels+=4;
}
glUnmapBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER);
glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, 0); /* unbind the PBO */

glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, bufferObject[RetrievingPixelBuffer]);
          /*          ^^^^^^--- You need to bind your PBO for UNPACKING! */
glDrawPixels(width, height, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));
glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, 0);
```

Comment: What I am trying to do is directly drawing pixels from/read GL_PACK_BUFFER into the frame buffer.

Comment: @giggle: OpenGL knows to kinds of pixel transfer operations: Packing and Unpacking. Packing means, content of an OpenGL framebuffer is written out, i.e. packed into a user buffer. Unpacking means content is read in, i.e. unpacked from a user buffer to a OpenGL framebuffer. glDrawPixels, glTexImage are unpacking. So you need to bind your pixel buffer object for unpacking.